# Unit testing Nest JS

Tags: nestjs

I have a little problem with my services dependencies for my unit test:

- I would test my UsersService who have three dependencies.
  [UsersService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZjK8.png)
- the  KeycloakUsersService itself has one dependency
  but if I try to mock the KeycloakUsersService as showed in the picture but I get this error :

[KeycloakUsersService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8JKP.png)
[KeycloakAdminClientService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISi8W.png)

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the KeycloakUsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument KeycloakAdminClientService at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

[Testing Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRU2F.png)

Comment: Are you sure it's the unit test spec that's causing the error? Also, please  paste code snippets rather than images. Images are hard to read and not accessible while code snippets help with SEO and indexing

Comment: Yes you was right, the error was not coming from the unit spec, and thx for the advice !